# Undo "Allow" for "Firefox prevented this page from automatically redirecting to another page"

Tags: firefox

I accidentally pressed "Allow" for a webpage when the popup with "Firefox prevented this page from automatically redirecting to another page" appeared, I would like to undo the "allow" that I did, but can't find out how.

Comment: Which OS? Firefox version?

Comment: @julien_c Windows 7, Firefox 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- [Clear Cookies & Cache](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Template:clearCookiesCache)
- [Clear the Network Cache](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/How%20to%20clear%20the%20cache#w_clear-the-cache)

Then :

1. click Firefox button and click Options -> Advanced -> General -> Remove Checkmark from Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload the page
2. Click OK on Options window -> Restart Firefox

[[Source on the mozilla support forum](http://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/868065#answer-238241)]

Comment: This is not the same problem, unlike him/her I want to keep the popup on this webpage. Just clearing the cookies (not even cache) was enough, problem solved...

Comment: Glad it helped though. Thanks for the feedback